# Best method to calculate the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a "gold" standard for computing the characteristic polynomial of a given $n \times n$ matrix in finite precision arithmetic on a computer?

There are fast methods running in $O(n^3)$ or even $O(n^\omega)$ :

- [An $O(n^3)$ algorithm for the Frobenius normal form by Storjohann](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.2505&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [Nearly optimal algorithms for canonical matrix forms by Giesbrecht](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~mwg/files/phdthesis.ps.Z)
- [Fast algorithms for the characteristics polynomial by Keller-Gehrig](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397585900490)

These algorithms are quite fast but were developed for finite fields and require randomness and matrix inversion, which in finite precision arithmetic can cause numerical problems.

On the other hand there is the Faddeev-Leverrier algorithm which only requires matrix multiplication but runs in time $O(n^4)$.

Does anyone have experience using these algorithms for numerical calculations?

Comment: Note that finite precision arithmetic and working in finite field $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ is roughly equivalent since real numbers on computer are stored under the form $x=M.2^{-n}$, this is why these algorithms were developed for finite fields.

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405822/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-matrix/405975#405975).